# How to use sed with regex

Tags: regex, linux, replace, sed

I want to replace in a text-file the char **|** to **##** everywhere respecting a pattern (pattern: **{ link | text }** )

So i have the in_file, for example

```
something
word [ http://problem | is here ]
{ http://no-problem.com | here } text and text { http://np.com | no problem }
```

The result must be:

```
something
word [ http://problem | is here ]
{ http://no-problem.com ## here ] text and text [[ http://np.com ## no problem ]]
```

Comment: Why the closing curly brace changed to `]` ?

Comment: couldn't you just `s/##/|/g` ?

Comment: Please don't put *[SOLVED]* in the title. The status (solved or unsolved) is already visible.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
$ cat file
something
word [ http://problem | is here ]
{ http://no-problem.com | here } text and text { http://np.com | no problem }
```

---

```
$ sed -r 's~(\{[^{]*https?://[^|}]*)\|([^}]*\})~\1##\2~g' file
something
word [ http://problem | is here ]
{ http://no-problem.com ## here } text and text { http://np.com ## no problem }
```

Comment: It's OK. But if i modify it to smth like: 
`{~ http://link.com | Text #}` it doesnt work

Comment: Then `sed -r 's~(\{[^{]*https?://[^|}]*)\|([^}]*\})~\1##\2~g' file` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You will need grouping and non-greedy expressions. Something like:

https://regex101.com/r/kM1hX3/1

Where you can experiment and tune the expressions to your real need, and find the explanation to the right.

However, it is in php format, that may need some tweaking too.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
sed -i.bak 's/\({ *http[^|]*\)|\([^|]*}\)/\1##\2/g' my_file
```

this command makes the actual changes and make a backup before whatever changes

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/\({[^|}]*\)|\([^|}]*}\)/\1##\2/g' file
something
word [ http://problem | is here ]
{ http://no-problem.com ## here } text and text { http://np.com ## no problem }
```